# How to create the derived object copy when the object passed as Base type? C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, copy

I'm having this design right now: (Notice IWorker is an abstract class)

[image: UML diagram]

as you can see the function "addWorker" is pure virtual and implemented in the lower class Manager.

My problem is here:

```
void Manager::addWorker(IWorker* worker) {
    this->_workers.push_back(worker);
    worker->setBoss(this);
}
```

1) The compiler can't create IWorker object for the vector _workers. What is 
   the right way to solve this problem? I thought to go with prototype 
   design and force all IWorker objects to implement copy() method and use 
   it there.

2) Is it good for IWorker to hold _boss as an IWorker object or should I try 
   pointers approach as IWorker* ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's no such thing as a IWorker object (since it's abstract) so Worker can't hold an IWorker object only an IWorker* pointer. Similarly you can't have a vector<IWorker> but you can have vector<IWorker*>. Also think carefully about using smart pointers not raw pointers. Not easy to tell from this snippett what kind of pointer you should be using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> force all IWorker objects to implement copy() method and use it there.

no, that does not solve the problem

> I try pointers approach as IWorker*

yes, `vector<IWorker>` must be `vector<IWorker *>`

Note that in `Manager::addWorker` you already suppose you have a vector of pointer

P.S.

Out of your problem why do you not use realization and generalization to indicate the inheritances ?

> function "addWorker" is pure virtual and implemented in the lower class Manager

If this is true that means the *Manager* is a *Worker*, are you **really** sure of that ? Generally the *Manager* is an independent class who doesn't not inherit the class it manages, and can be a *singleton*

Are you sure to understand what an inheritance is ?

Comment: All the fields: id, name, salary are shared among every general worker, I wanted to put them in a highest class. Later on I need to print all the workers starting from the CEO that's why I used virtual function printWorker, in the case of Manager printing it uses the printWorker of Worker and then print all his workers recursively. Can you consider a better way to design it? I used composite as every object contains the general object as a member.

Comment: @EladAharon that change nothing, a `vector<IWorker>` can only contain _IWorker_, not a sub class instance. And because _IWorker_ is abstract you cannot instantiate it, so it is not possible to have `vector<IWorker>` who need to instantiate it. This has non sense for the instance of a sub class to have a relation to her corresponding parent instance, the subclass instance already contains the parent class instance, in a single inheritance the addresses are the same

Comment: I got it, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is one pattern for copying derived objects from base class pointers, it just uses the copy constructor in each derived class and a virtual function `clone`.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
};

class Derived
{
public:
    virtual Derived* clone() const { return new Derived(*this); }
};
```

Similar code is possible for smart pointers too.

Comment: Thank you! Can I also overload the operator "=" in order to achieve the same results?